# Why does IE11 fail to send the post form?

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

More details,

I use a simple post Ajax call (used Jquery but also the native XMLhttpRequest with the form encoded as url encoded.

```
myPost: function(url,form,doneCallback,failedCallback){
    var mypost = new XMLHttpRequest();
    mypost.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (mypost.readyState === 4){
            doneCallback(mypost);
        }
    };
    mypost.onerror = function() {
        failedCallback(mypost);
    };
    mypost.open('POST',url,true);
    mypost.setRequestHeader('Content-Length', result.length);
    mypost.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    mypost.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    mypost.setRequestHeader('Connection','close');
    mypost.send(form);

},
```

In both situations the code works just fine with Chrome, Safari, Firefox and on IE 11 on win 8.1 or win 7 as a VM on VMWare Fusion, so running on a Mac OsX 10.9.2 with the latest win 8.1 updates installed. However as soon as this code runs on a native windows 8.1 version and IE with the same version for OS and IE, the post forgets to put out the post payload no matter whether I put the above header attributes in or not.

And yes a chrome browser on native win 8.1 properly puts the payload to the server, while the native IE 11 does not put the payload out. The receiving server linux based restlet is missing the payload for the specified resource so further returns a "500" status at the application layer.

There must be some configuration difference with respect to the IE on the native and the VM. As far as I can see this is different from what similar question have described.

BTW on the same native windows 8.1 some posts are working that address a form already created on the web pages, while the above form date is simply filled as.
    form = 'options='+encodeURIComponent(options);

Any idea where the different behaviour is created?

Thanks

Comment: I'm sharing your pain... i have the same problem. Did you ever come right. I'm contemplating changing our entire system to push all the body content into URL parameters and just read them off there on the server side...but gosh how messy!

Comment: @peter, I Have not found an answer yet as the need for a solution got pushed out.

Answer (score 0):

```
mypost.setRequestHeader('Content-Length', result.length);
mypost.setRequestHeader('Connection','close');
```

those lines are only working in FireFox for me, if I remove those 2 lines, my code is working in IE11.